# How to save html form data to sql db using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, forms

I'm new to this and haven't saved html form data so far.
Can someone please guide about how to save the html form elements like first name, last name, password, email to sql database using javascript or jquery?

Comment: You shouldn't do such a thing directly.  Databases should not be exposed to the Internet.  Put an intermediary between your page and database to validate, bind, and provide security.

Comment: Generally your JavaScript code wouldn't connect to the database.  It would post the values to a server-side resource (web page, web service, etc.) which would interact with the database.  Have you made *any* attempt at this?  Maybe walked through some tutorials on developing a database-driven web page?

Comment: We can not directly access SQL server from JS. For that you have create web service / wcf service.

Comment: Do some basic research on how web forms work. This site is for code issues

Comment: database can't be accessed directly by JS, you should look at AJAX.

Comment: Thanks Guys :) Ill start working on it then..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be done directly. JS is executed by the client browser, and need a middleware to allow saving the data in a MySQL DB.

[Here is a link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm) to a tutorial on how to save data to a MySQL DB